# How do I run Aptana Studio 3 as root in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, aptana, root

I recently installed Aptana Studio 3 on Ubuntu (13.04) and I need to run it as root so I can save PHP Files to the www directory of my server.  I installed it from their site since it's not in the repositories so I'm not sure what the sudo command would be for it.  I tried

```
sudo aptana
sudo aptana-studio
sudo aptanastudio
sudo aptanastudio3
```

None of them worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This question might be better suited to our sister site, http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run as root, do `su -` then run Aptana from the command line as normal, however...

You shouldn't require root priveleges to write to the /var/www directory (this would suggest that your Apache process has root access), you should add your user to the `www-data` group (or whatever group owns the dir) and then give group write access to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
>su - root
[You'll need to type your password]
# aptana-studio
```

Remember to add the proper executable to the path so you can invoke it, propably would be a good idea to edit you bashrc or equivalent file.

Best regards.

EDIT: If you want to keep the process running independently from the terminal you're executing aptana then you should try with`#aptana-studio &`

Answer (score 0):

Help can be found at aptana studio's download page. I'd recommend you visit it and take some time reading what they have to say about installation and startup guide.